# Is it possible to customize Sharepoint document versioning?

Tags: sharepoint

Sharepoint's default version pattern for Major.Minor versions is N.N.

Is it possible to change this pattern to NN.MMYY, where N is a digit and MMYY is a datecode?

Comment: I'd say "maybe with a workflow or an event receiver", and direct you to [our SharePoint-dedicated sister site](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

What version of SharePoint are you using? I will answer for SharePoint 2007 (MOSS or WSS). The answer for 2010 might be a bit different but I suspect that the information will still be valid.

In short, no you can't. The reason being that though you only see the Major.Minor label for a document, there is a lot more in the background.

The version of a list item is based on many hidden columns, namely :

```
ows_owshiddenversion
ows__UIVersion
ows__UIVersionString
```

ows_owshiddenversion is an integer. If you have 6 revisions for an item (regardless of them being major or minor revisions) the values stored in there will be 1,2,3,4,5,6

ows_*UIVersion takes into account the major / minor. A major revision will add 512 to the ows*_UIVersion field (not exactly, but see the example below to understand)

```
Label            ows_UIVersion
Version 1.0  --> 512
Version 1.1  --> 513
Version 1.2  --> 514
Version 2.0  --> 1024
Version 2.1  --> 1025
```

The ows_owshiddenversion field, combined with the ows_*UIVersion will give you the ows*_UIVersionString which is displayed to the user.

To change that, you would have to change pre-defined columns which touch the inner workings of SharePoint. Even if it was possible, you would most likely end up with a massive headache.

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate version number by creating a calculated field in the format you want and using that field value. Could be anough for you